# Is it possible to bind a date/time to a console log?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have the following code:

```
var myLog = console.log.bind(console, '[DEBUG]');
```

Which works find when I want to log things prepended with `[DEBUG]` to the console.
Now I want to add a date/time to the log and I tried this:

```
var myLog = console.log.bind(console, '[DEBUG ' + (new Date) + ']');
```

Which obviously does not work because it **always** logs the same time (the time that the `.bind` was called).

Is there any way (using `.bind`) to log the current time on each log **without** having to do this:

```
var myLog = function(){
    var args = ['[DEBUG ' + (new Date) + ']'];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return console.log.apply(console, args);
};
```

?

Because the above method shows me the line that `console.log.apply` was called and **not** the line that `myLog` was called.

Comment: You could extract the line where it was called from `Error().stack`

Comment: @copy that is what I was already doing... But that does not allow for you to click on it in the console to get to the line in the source file

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/SwFJg/6/

```
var DEBUG = (function(){
    var timestamp = function(){};
    timestamp.toString = function(){
        return "[DEBUG " + (new Date).toLocaleTimeString() + "]";    
    };

    return {
        log: console.log.bind(console, '%s', timestamp)
    }
})();

DEBUG.log("banana", {foo:'bar'}); //[DEBUG 2:43:21 PM] banana Object {foo: "bar"}
console.log("Peppercorn");        //Peppercorn 
DEBUG.log("apple");               //[DEBUG 2:43:21 PM] apple 
DEBUG.log("orange");              //[DEBUG 2:43:21 PM] orange 
setTimeout(function(){
    DEBUG.log("mango");           //[DEBUG 2:43:25 PM] mango 
},3000)
```

This works because `toString` is called on `timestamp` (and, in fact, everything) each time `console.log` is called.

We overwrite the default `toString` method, and replace it with a time stamp (obviously you can change the output to whatever you want).

I chose the above pattern because, as others have noted (in SO chat), you can easily extend the DEBUG object to do other things.

```
...
return {
    log: console.log.bind(console, '%s', timestamp),
    error: console.error.bind(console, '%s', timestamp),
    info: console.info.bind(console, '%s', timestamp),
    warn: console.warn.bind(console, '%s', timestamp),
    group: ...,
    groupEnd: ...,
    groupCollapsed: ... // etc
}
...
```

Comment: I think you could simplify the code if you just pass an object with a `toString` method directly to the function: `console.log.bind(console, {toString: function()  {...}})`. No need to create `DEBUG` or empty functions. Good idea though!

Comment: I see, makes sense. At least in Firefox you can enforce the evaluation as a string: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/SwFJg/4/. Although this is also supported in Chrome, it just shows `Object`. Note that your solution doesn't seem to work in Firefox for me, but if you enforce string evaluation, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/SwFJg/5/.

Comment: @FelixKling weird. To be honest, the question isn't completely relevant to FF since it already includes timestamps. It is a little concerning that it prevents anything from being logged though.

Is there a way to remove the enforced string evaluation?

Comment: is there a way to bind more than one function ? 
what I mean is if I want to log something other than timestamp that would take a variable beside the time stamp not on other line

Comment: `let originalLog = console.log;
console.log = (...args)=>{
    originalLog(dayjs().format("[[]DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss]"),...args);
}
` Just copy paste this (it's using dayjs for the format).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for, which is simple

```
console.logCopy = console.debug.bind(console);

console.debug = function(data)
{
    var currentDate = '[' + new Date().toUTCString() + '] ';
    this.logCopy(currentDate, data);
};
```

Comment: This only logs if you pass only one thing to console log. If you pass multiple things they get lost

Comment: If you want to support multiple parameters, you can use my solution here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814221/adding-timestamps-to-all-console-messages/36887315#36887315