# Adding timestamps to all console messages

Tags: node.js, express, console

I have a complete, *deployed*, Express-based project, with many console.log() and console.error() statements throughout. 
The project runs using forever, directing the stdout and stderr to 2 separate files.

It all works quite well, but now I'm missing timestamps - to know exactly when errors occurred.

I can do some kind of search/replace throughout my code, or use some npm module that overrides console in each file, but I do not want to touch every model/route file, unless I absolutely have to.

Is there a way, perhaps an Express middleware, that would allow me to add a timestamp to every call made, or do I have to manually add it?

Comment: Closely related: [Is it possible to bind a date/time to a console log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410119/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-date-time-to-a-console-log) and [console.log timestamps in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008120/console-log-timestamps-in-chrome)

Comment: @Vipul this is a NodeJS question (backend), not a Chrome console question.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It turns out, you **can** override the console functions at the top of the app.js file, and have it take effect in every other module. I got mixed results because one of my modules is forked as a `child_process`. Once I copied the line to the top of that file as well, all works.

For the record, I installed the module [console-stamp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-stamp) (`npm install console-stamp --save`), and added this line to the top of app.js and childProcess.js:

```js
// add timestamps in front of log messages
require('console-stamp')(console, '[HH:MM:ss.l]');
```

My problem now was that the `:date` format of the connect logger uses UTC format, rather than the one I'm using in the other console calls. That was easily fixed by registering my own time format (and as a side effect, requiring the `dateformat` module that `console stamp` comes with, rather than installing another one):

```
// since logger only returns a UTC version of date, I'm defining my own date format - using an internal module from console-stamp
express.logger.format('mydate', function() {
    var df = require('console-stamp/node_modules/dateformat');
    return df(new Date(), 'HH:MM:ss.l');
});
app.use(express.logger('[:mydate] :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :remote-addr - :response-time ms'));
```

Now my log files look organized (and better yet, parseable):

```
[15:09:47.746] staging server listening on port 3000
[15:09:49.322] connected to database server xxxxx successfully
[15:09:52.743] GET /product 200 - - 127.0.0.1 - 214 ms
[15:09:52.929] GET /stylesheets/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css 304 - - 127.0.0.1 - 8 ms
[15:09:52.935] GET /javascripts/vendor/require.js 304 - - 127.0.0.1 - 3 ms
[15:09:53.085] GET /javascripts/product.js 304 - - 127.0.0.1 - 2 ms
...
```

Comment: I could not find the docs for it, but it appears that ":mm" will refer to the month, and ":MM" is the format that you actually want to use

Comment: you shoud change the minutes part according to what says @user603124 . For minutes the string is **:MM** (https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp)

Comment: Seems like you no longer need to wrap HH:MM:ss.l in brackets -- it is doing it automatically

Comment: FYI `logger` has been replaced by `morgan` https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

Answer (score 82):

The module [log-timestamp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-timestamp) works for me.

```
npm install log-timestamp
```

It's simple to use:

```js
console.log('Before log-timestamp');
require('log-timestamp');
console.log('After log-timestamp');
```

```
Before log-timestamp
[2012-08-23T20:08:32.000Z] After log-timestamp
```

Answer (score 36):

Create a file with the following:

```
var log = console.log;

console.log = function(){
  log.apply(console, [Date.now()].concat(arguments));
};
```

Require it in your app before you log anything. Do the same for `console.error` if needed.

Note that this solution will destroy variable insertion (`console.log("he%s", "y") // "hey"`) if you're using that. If you need that, just log the timestamp first:

```
log.call(console, Date.now());
log.apply(console, arguments);
```

Comment: Not if it's the same app/process. Console is a global object so if you hijack one of its functions like this it will keep being hijacked for all files which share that global object.

Comment: So this should/could be placed in the app.js file?

Comment: Yes. <min 15 chars...>

Comment: I recommend using console-stamp instead

Comment: This is not good solution - it either destroys variable insertion (thus can't be used as replacement), or prints date and log output on different lines.

Comment: a proper way to do it is 

const log = console.log;

console.log = function(){
    log.apply(console, [new Date(), ...arguments]);
};

Answer (score 27):

If you want a solution without another external dependency but you want to keep the full functionalities of console.log (multiple parameters, variable insertion) you can use the following code:

```
var log = console.log;

console.log = function () {
    var first_parameter = arguments[0];
    var other_parameters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    function formatConsoleDate (date) {
        var hour = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        var milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds();

        return '[' +
               ((hour < 10) ? '0' + hour: hour) +
               ':' +
               ((minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes: minutes) +
               ':' +
               ((seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds: seconds) +
               '.' +
               ('00' + milliseconds).slice(-3) +
               '] ';
    }

    log.apply(console, [formatConsoleDate(new Date()) + first_parameter].concat(other_parameters));
};
```

You can modify the formatConsoleDate function to format the date how you want.

This code needs to be written only once on top of your main JavaScript file.

`console.log("he%s", "y")` will print something like this:

```
[12:22:55.053] hey
```

Comment: Thanks, this "no dependencies" answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: that messes up the file:line information :(

Comment: That solution can't output objects. It will simply out "[Object object]". Instead of concatenating the timestamp and first_parameter, just treat them as two parameters: 
`log.apply(console, [formatConsoleDate(new Date()), first_parameter].concat(other_parameters));`

(replace '+' with ',')

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the [log-timestamp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-timestamp) package. It's quite straightforward, and customizable as well.

Answer (score 7):

This implementation is simple, supports original functionality of console.log (passing a single object, and variable substitution), doesn't use external modules and prints everything in a single call to console.log:

```
var origlog = console.log;

console.log = function( obj, ...placeholders ){
    if ( typeof obj === 'string' )
        placeholders.unshift( Date.now() + " " + obj );
    else
    {
        // This handles console.log( object )
        placeholders.unshift( obj );
        placeholders.unshift( Date.now() + " %j" );
    }

    origlog.apply( this, placeholders );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, compared to other implementations from this thread this one seems quite straightforward and seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish, you may create a custom logger for your application by extending the Node's build in "Console" class. Kindly refer to the following implementation

```js
"use strict";

const moment = require('moment');
const util = require('util');
const Console = require('console').Console;

class Logger extends Console {
    constructor(stdout, stderr, ...otherArgs) {
        super(stdout, stderr, ...otherArgs);
    }

    log(...args) {
        super.log(moment().format('D MMM HH:mm:ss'), '-', util.format(...args));
    }

    error(...args) {
        super.error(moment().format('D MMM HH:mm:ss'), '-', util.format(...args));
    }
}

module.exports = (function() {
    return new Logger(process.stdout, process.stderr); 
}());
```

After that, you may use it in your code as :

```js
const logger = require('./logger');

logger.log('hello world', 123456);
logger.error('some error occurred', err);
```

Comment: I liked this answer however the performance is very bad.

Answer (score 5):

A more rudimentary approach, to avoid installing external modules, could be implementing a simple function such as:

```
function timeStamp(message){
    console.log ( '[' + new Date().toISOString().substring(11,23) + '] -', message )
}
```

and then I simply call it in this way:

```
timeStamp('this is my logline!!');
```

the result will be:

```
 LOG  [15:22:30.682] - this is my logline!!
```

of course you can format the date in the best format you need and expand the function to console.error, debug, etc.

Answer (score 4):

An answer suitable for 2022

```
const log = console.log;

console.log = function(){
    log.apply(console, [new Date(), ...arguments]);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer, but have you looked into winston.js? It has a ton more logging options including logging to a json file or database. These always have timestamps by default. Just a thought.

Comment: I've looked into many things, right now, I'd like to add something to an existing, deployed project - without touching too much of the code

Answer (score 3):

```
app.use(morgan('[:date[web]] :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :remote-addr - :response-time ms'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function `util.log` from https://nodejs.org/api/util.html.

Be aware that it was deprecated since version 6.0.0.

For higher versions you should ["Use a third party module instead."](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_log_string)

Comment: Deprecated: use a third party module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying overwriting the `console` object - seems to be working well. To use, save the code below in a file, and then import to overwrite the proxy object, and then use as normal.

(Note this requires babel transpilation and won't work in environments that don't support the JavaScript `Proxy` constructor such as IE 11).

```
import console from './console-shadow.js'

console.log(...)
console.warn(...)
console.error(...)
```

```
// console-shadow.js

// Only these functions are shadowed by default
const overwrites = ['log', 'warn', 'info', 'error']

export default new Proxy(
  // Proxy (overwrite console methods here)
  {},

  // Handler
  {
    get: (obj, prop) =>
      prop in obj
        ? obj[prop]
        : overwrites.includes(prop)
        ? (...args) => console[prop].call(console, new Date(), ...args)
        : console[prop],
  }
)
```

Basically I overwrite the console object with a JavaScript proxy object. When you call `.log`, `.warn`, etc. the overwritten console will check if what you are calling is a function, if so it will inject a date into the log statement as the first parameter, followed by all your parameters.

I think the `console` object actually does a lot, and I don't fully understand it. So I only intercept `console.log`, `console.info`, `console.warn`, `console.error` calls.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @AndreasHultgren's solution but it did not accept arguments so I expanded on it.

```
let warnLog = console.warn;
console.warn = (...strings) => {
    let firstFormat = strings.shift();
    let dateFormat = '[' + date.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + '] WARN: ' + firstFormat;
    strings.unshift(dateFormat);
    warnLog(...strings);
};

let errorLog = console.error;
console.error = (...strings) => {
    let firstFormat = strings.shift();
    let dateFormat = '[' + date.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + '] ERROR: ' + firstFormat;
    strings.unshift(dateFormat);
    errorLog(...strings);
};
```

Far off in another part of my NodeJS project.

```
console.error('settings being read by %s and %s', 'steve', 'tom');
console.warn('Your %s wears %s', 'mother', 'army boots');
```

[image]

Comment: Also added a third one for console.info(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can allways use log4j, as its written in doku [to use third party tools](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_log_string).

I can recommend using the [log4j](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js). It does gives more than time but this is a good entry for the future impovements as well.

Please find below example implementation

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.level = 'info';
logger.log('your log message');
```

Example output

> [2023-05-01T15:24:12.948] [INFO] default - your log message

Answer (score -1):

Use event listener like this,

```
process.on('error', function() { 
   console.log('Error Occurred.');

   var d = Date(Date.now()).toString();
   console.log.call(console, d); // Wed Aug 07 2019 23:40:07 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
});
```

happy coding :)